# Ubuntu not detecting drives inside ssd while installation alongside Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I have a HP laptop with windows pre installed. It has a 512gb uefi, gpt ssd with 3 drives C:, D: and E:. I want to install ubuntu in E: drive and along with the applications of ubuntu. But ubuntu does not recognize the partitions C:,D: or E: while installation, which is why I need help.

Here are the partition details in windows:

[image: Disk Management.exe]

Ubuntu installation only shows:

- `/dev/nvme0n1`
- `/dev/nvme1n1`

Also I want to mention I have never used Linux or Ubuntu before.

Comment: How are you booting into the Ubuntu installer? Are you choosing to "Restart Windows"? If so, you will likely need to choose "Shut Down", *then* boot the machine with the Ubuntu installation device in place. Windows will occasionally "keep" devices to itself when rebooting.

Comment: You have one drive divided in to 3 partitions which have the Windows names c and d etc. You can not install Ubuntu into a Windows drive letter. A must read before you do anything. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: @David I did try deleting the E: drive from windows and restart the ubuntu installation from bootable usb stick, but the problem still persists.

Comment: @matigo I am not choosing restart in Windows, I am shutting down and then turning on the pc and then booting through a bootable usb stick with the iso file.

Comment: You need to read about how to delete a PARTITION in Windows and do that. That is how you free up space.

Comment: @David Do you mean [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EzAt.png). I deleted one  partition and now have 168gb unallocated space. The problem still persists.

Comment: A default install should now work.

Comment: When the installer ask 'how do you want to install Ubuntu' click on 'something else'. Then you can select the free space on the disk and install Ubuntu.

Comment: Make sure Windows fast start up & bitlocker are off, so installer can see the NTFS partitions. You may want UEFI Secure boot off, if you need nVidia proprietary driver. It can be installed with Secure boot on, but a bit more complicated about MOK keys you have to create to verify driver. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, my laptop has an intel optane memory, which was messing up the ubuntu installation. After disabling the optane memory and restarting the installation, ubuntu detected all the partitions as expected.